# Hang at BIOS with USB sound card. HP dc7900 SFF

Tags: boot, usb, bios, sound-card

I can not boot my HP dc7900 small form factor with USB sound card plugged in.

USB sound card in question: [Creative 
SoundBlaster Live 24 Bit External USB (SB0490)](http://support.creative.com/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?catID=1&prodID=10702&prodName=Live!%2024-bit%20External&CatName=Sound%20Blaster)

BIOS would start to count RAM and then stop after second or less, or just blank screen shows up.

Without it, Windows boots normally, everything else works.
BIOS updated, installed Q8400 processor, increased fan speed, to fully manage heat emission.

I am looking for solution to boot with USB sound card inserted. Not having it plugged in is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're managing heat, sounds like a lot of other devices already in the system.

Test with a larger power supply, very possible as the devices are initializing you're exceeding max output of the existing power supply.

Comment: Can it exceed power just on booting? PSU is 240w, whats inside - geforce 210 GPU, Intel Q8400, three ram sticks, ssd and hdd, mouse, keyboard, plus usb soundcard. I dont believe that it exceeds power, because no matter what configuration of devices there is, even if no hdd and gpu. PC wont start bios. Maybe just USB is overloaded?

Comment: The single highest power usage of a PC is when it boots and it's powering all the devices of the system online (spinning up motors/fans etc). If it won't POST, remove all devices and see if it boots. Still nothing, again replace power supply maybe one of the two transformers in there isn't providing either 5v or 12v. Still no POST after testing with new power supply you can try reseating RAM/CPU...after that it's a bad part on the motherboard most likely. USB overload will NOT stop system from POSTing.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried to boot up with as little devices as I could - no gpu, hdd, ram. As this is SFF, it kind of hard to find replacement. It will bootup with whatever configuration without USB soundcard. It can boot up with external HDD.